# AWS PrivateLink S3 to S3 copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy the data in one of my S3 bucket, to another customer's S3 bucket. But, the criteria is that it needs to go through AWS PrivateLink.

So far my understanding is that I have to copy the data to S3 using the first PrivateLink (from my bucket) to EC2, and then use the other PrivateLink (the one with the customer) to copy data to the customer's S3 bucket.

Is it possible to have S3 to S3 direct copy using AWS PrivateLink?

Comment: Can you tell us more about _why_ you have a requirement that data "goes through PrivateLink"? I suspect that this is saying "...as opposed to across the Internet", but when data is copied between Amazon S3 buckets in the same region, it does _not_ go across the Internet -- it is handled totally within the S3 infrastructure. The most efficient (and secure) method would be to use the `CopyObject` command to copy the data directly between the buckets. The _command_ to trigger this copy could be issued via PrivateLink, but the data would _not_ go through PrivateLink. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What happens when copying across the regions  using CopyObject ? Does it goes via public network ?

Comment: Aryan:From [Does traffic between Amazon EC2 and Amazon S3 really go over the internet? | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU4fn697qVTRWaB0rhGZfHZw/does-traffic-between-amazon-ec-2-and-amazon-s-3-really-go-over-the-internet): _"All network traffic between regions is encrypted, stays on the AWS global network backbone, and never traverses the public internet, thereby reducing threat vectors, such as common exploits and DDoS attacks."_ You can alternatively use [Inter-Region VPC Peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/).

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is more general that the data should not traverse the public internet between buckets (as raised by others), then a good (and free) solution would be to provision Gateway VPC Endpoint for the S3 service within the source and target accounts that contain the S3 buckets with the objects of interest.